# How to get dl dds to line up with each other

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
dt
{
clear:left;
float:left;
padding-right:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<dl>
<dt>First Answer</dt>
<dd>Dog</dd>
<dt>Second Answer</dt>
<dd>Cat</dd>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

When you run it the Dog and Cat don't line up. I was really hoping to get the first letters of Dog and Cat to line up with each other.

Does anyone know how to style this to achieve this?

Rather not use a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a fixed width on the dt element.

```
dt
{
clear:left;
float:left;
width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated HTML/CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
dt{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    padding-right:50px;
    width:200px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <dl>
       <dt>First Answer</dt>
       <dd>Dog</dd>
       <dt>Second Answer</dt>
       <dd>Cat</dd>
       </dl>
</body>
```

This is your updated code...